# Unable to connect to proper database using mongo script

Tags: mongodb, shell

I've written a script that takes in some variables and updates my db accordingly. I seem to get a connection to the wrong database every time I try to run my script in the command line:

```
conn = new Mongo();
db = conn.getDB("my_db");

db.auth({
    user:DB_USER, 
    password: DB_PASSWORD
});

cust = db.customers;

print('===== Indexes before execution =====');
print(JSON.stringify(db.customers.getIndexes()));

cust.createIndex({geo_point:"2dsphere"});

print('===== Indexes after execution =====');
print(JSON.stringify(db.customers.getIndexes()));
```

This is how I'm running it: `mongo --eval 'let DB_USER="usr", DB_PASSWORD="pwd"' script.js`

and this is the output: `MongoDB shell version: 3.2.16
connecting to: test
2017-09-20T22:51:08.589+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell eval):1:4`

As you can see it says "connecting to test". Not sure what that's about, also, not sure what it means by `missing ; before statement @(shell eval):1:4`

Please note that when I run `mongo` in the shell I get

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.16
connecting to: test
```

All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `mongo mongodb://<user>:<password>@localhost/<database> script.js` You don't mix `--eval` and script input, and you provided your credentials when invoking the shell. The shell is just a "tool" anyway. If you want a serious program, then use a programming language.

Comment: Thanks for the input--is this the recommended way to execute a script? I have to run the script in to multiple databases. There's no way to pass the db connection to the script other than --eval (which works when I tested it)... Thanks again!

Comment: You are asking "why does it say connecting to test"? The answer is "because that's the database you are actually connecting to". There is nothing stopping you "swicthing" the database during a script as long as you have permission to do so. It's really just a `db.getSiblingDB()` call, You are overthinking all of this, and again if you have a big task "get a real programming language"

Comment: Okay, thanks, tried that previously and didn't work db.getSiblingDB() yields the same as the previous.